# Play framework 1.x redirect delete action

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to redirect an action call from one controller to another controller. ListController displays a list of entries and shall have a delete button for each. I don't want to use the concrete EntryController call in the view, because I have a few simular Controllers that I want to implement later.

For some reason play doesn't allow me to call the action on the EntryController, the program just jumps over the call line. Debuging the play code I found out that ControllerInstrumentation.isActionCallAllowed() returns false.

**ListController**

```
public static void delete(Long id) {
  EntryController.delete(id);
}
```

**ListController idndex view**

```
#{a @delete(id)}delete{/a}
```

**EntryController**

```
public static void delete(Long id) {
  Entry entry = Entry.findById(id);
  entry.delete();
}
```

**Routes**

```
DELETE /{id}         ListController.delete
DELETE /entries/{id} EntryController.delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

route says '`EntryController.delete`' accepts only '`DELETE`' method. So, when you make a direct function call, somewhat it makes an `HTTP GET` request . you should override the http method while redirecting.

**ListController**

```
public static void delete(Long id) {
    //EntryController.delete(id);
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("id", id);
    args.put("x-http-method-override", "DELETE");
    String fullUrl = Router.getFullUrl("EntryController.delete", args);
    redirect(fullUrl);
}
```